# Asp.net Core 2.0 Razor Pages Ajax Post

Tags: ajax, razor, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to just jquery ajax call to retrieve a list of users from a Razor page.

Users.cshtml.cs page:

```
public ActionResult OnPostList(string FirstName, string LastName,string IsActive)
{
        var data=(from s in _db.SecurityUser
                 where s.FirstName.Contains(FirstName) && s.LastName.Contains(LastName) && (IsActive=="" || (IsActive =="Y" && s.IsActive==true) || (IsActive == "N" && s.IsActive == false))
                 select s).OrderBy(s=>s.FirstName);
        return new JsonResult(data);
}
```

JS Call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Security/Users?handler=List",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        FirstName: $("#txtFirstName").val(),
        LastName: $("#txtLastName").val(),
        IsActive: $("#ddActive").val()
    }),
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        var d = response.d;
        var tblBody = $("#tblUsers > tbody");
        tblBody.empty();
        $.each(d, function (i, item) {
            var modifiedDate = new Date(parseInt(item.ModifiedDate.substr(6)));
            var $tr = $('<tr>').append(
                $('<td>').html("<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='fnDialogShow(" + item.UserID + ")'>Edit</a>"),
                $('<td>').text(item.FirstName),
                $('<td>').text(item.LastName),
                $('<td>').text(item.IsActive ? "Yes" : "No")
            ).appendTo(tblBody);

        });
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }

});
```

When it calls I get a 400 error back.  Trying to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You're calling the Action "*Users*" and not "*OnPostList*".

Answer (score 12):

Your URL formation for Ajax request is correct. One thing to note down is, Razor Pages are designed to be protected from (CSRF/XSRF) attacks. Hence, Antiforgery token generation and validation are automatically included in Razor Pages. I believe that is the problem here. Your page may have antiforgery token present on the page if you have form tag in your HTML. But you need to pass the same in your Ajax request.

First, add antiforgery token using `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`, if not present.

Then, modify your Ajax request to send the same in request header.

Like,

```js
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
       xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
          $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
},
```

Read this post [Handle Ajax Requests in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/handle-ajax-requests-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages/)  to know more about making ajax request with ASP.NET Core razor pages.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, see microsoft docs for working example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery#javascript

Answer (score 9):

for .net core 2.1 the solution from this blog helped 
https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/asp-net-core-razor-pages-how-to-implement-ajax-requests/

if the page does not contain form with method post, add antiforgery token `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`

and you can start to fire ajax request, important part is to set **headers** here.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Customers?handler=Delete",
                data: { id: id },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                // AntiforgeryToken is required by RazorPages
                headers: {
                    RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                }
            })
            .done(function () {
                alert("success");
            })
            .fail(function () { 
                alert("error");
            });
```

Comment: Working with .NET6 here. This was the simplest solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Razor Pages are designed to be protected CSRF attacks.

You must properly inject the antiforgery token into your ajax request.

[See the Documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery#javascript)

In ASP.NET Core 2.0 it looks like this...

First place this code into the top of your razor view:

```
// At the top of your page
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery Xsrf
@functions{
    public string GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()
    {
        return Xsrf.GetAndStoreTokens(Context).RequestToken;
    }
}
```

Then in your ajax request, set the token header.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    headers: {
        "RequestVerificationToken": '@GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()'
    },
    url: '@Url.Action("Antiforgery", "Home")',
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function (err, scnd) {
        alert(err.statusText);
    }
});
```

Comment: `Xsrf.GetAndStoreTokens(Context).RequestToken;` You may get a `Context` if you're using MVC, but not with Razor Pages.  Change to `Xsrf.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext).RequestToken;`

Comment: Nice catch @AdamVincent, I am certainly using MVC in conjunction with Razor Pages

Answer (score 0):

Mark your OnPostList with HttpPost attribute and change your URL in ajax call to /Security/OnPostList

Answer (score 0):

add     `[HttpPost]` in Action

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult OnPostList(string FirstName, string LastName,string IsActive)
    {
            var data=(from s in _db.SecurityUser
                     where s.FirstName.Contains(FirstName) && s.LastName.Contains(LastName) && (IsActive=="" || (IsActive =="Y" && s.IsActive==true) || (IsActive == "N" && s.IsActive == false))
                     select s).OrderBy(s=>s.FirstName);
            return new JsonResult(data);
    }
```

---

Used this `Script` in     `Users.cshtml.cs`

```
<script>
  var url='@(Url.Action("OnPostList","ControllerName"))';
  var firstName= $("#txtFirstName").val();
  var lastName= $("#txtLastName").val();
  var isActive= $("#ddActive").val();
  $.post(Url,{FirstName:firstName,LastName=lastName,IsActive=isActive},function(data){
      var d = data.d;
      var tblBody = $("#tblUsers > tbody");
      tblBody.empty();
      $.each(d, function (i, item) {
         var modifiedDate = new Date(parseInt(item.ModifiedDate.substr(6)));
         var $tr = $('<tr>').append(
         $('<td>').html("<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='fnDialogShow(" + item.UserID + ")'>Edit</a>"),
         $('<td>').text(item.FirstName),
         $('<td>').text(item.LastName),
         $('<td>').text(item.IsActive ? "Yes" : "No")
         ).appendTo(tblBody);
       });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had bad experiences with $.ajax, I used $.post instead.
I used validateAntiforgeryToken but its not necessary

```
    $("#emailSubmit").click(function () {

        $.post("/Projects/SendInvite",
            {
                Email: $("#email").val(),
                Message: $("#message").val(),
                __RequestVerificationToken: $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
            }

        )
        return false;

    });
```

And this is net core action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult SendInvite(string Email, string Message)
{

        //MailTest();
        var json = new List<string>
        {
        Email,
        Message
        };
        return new JsonResult(json);
   }
```